# Struts2 Form Resubmission With Validation

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

Good Day!

I have used token interceptor and everything is going great.
However, a problem came up with the update feature of our application.
Upon update, I load the information on the form (the same form with adding an information).
If there is an invalid information, the form reloads with the corresponding messages.
Using the token interceptor, when the user wishes to reload the page using "refresh", the
user is redirected to the form for adding an information and not on the update form.
This happens because on the result type for "invalid.token", it is redirected to the "add" action.

So my problem is, how to redirect to the "update" action when there is already a defined result for "invalid.token" which is the redirection to the "add" action.

Thank you. :)

Code for save action:

```
   @Action(
    interceptorRefs={
    @InterceptorRef("token"),
    @InterceptorRef("defaultStack"),
    @InterceptorRef("adminAdminManagerStack")
},
value="saveSkillGranularity",
results={
    @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "SkillGranularityForm", type="tiles"),
    @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type = "redirect", location="listSkillGranularity"),
    @Result(name = ActionSupport.LOGIN, location = "login", type = "redirect"),
    @Result(name = "invalid.token", location = "addSkillGranularity", type = "redirectAction")
}
)
public String saveSkillGranularity() {
    if (getStatus().equals("add")) {
    skillGranularityService.addSkillGranularity(skillGranularity.getName());
}
else {
    skillGranularityService.updateSkillGranularity(skillGranularity.getSkillGranularityId(), skillGranularity.getName());
}

return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Added code for the save action. the form for the add and update points to the save action. :)

Comment: Tell the exact steps to reproduce the problem. Also use `redirectAction` result instead of `redirect`.

Comment: I used **redirectAction** and the problem is still present. Using the form, input invalid information, and the page will load with corresponding error messages. And then "refresh" the page. :)